# Netbeans can't show design button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm newbie of netbeans, but I install it on my Macbook to try to crete some java GUI applications.
This is what I do :

1. create a new java application project
2. create a swing GUI forms

well, now on my screen a can see the design tool to create my application with the swing controls(label, button,etcc..),but if I don't click 2 times on the object , I can't see the code of the object.
In short, I haven't got the two button to slide between code and design tool .
how I can solve this problem ?
I've already try to check if java EE plugins are activated (like some forum suggested me ) and I try to find the solution in the windows palette of netbeans .
My hardware is a macbook 12 " late 2015 and Netbeans 8.2

Comment: Do you see a "Designer" tab at the top of your design window? Nearby there should be a "Source" tab. What happens if you go to Menu -> View -> Editors -> Source?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Maya , your answer it's very helpful, in fact in the palette view I select to "show editor toolbar"